# webRequest doen't work from different user

Tags: c#, .net, networking, httpwebrequest

I build a small winform application that use some API for sending sms messages,
when i run it on my station with my user everything works great but if i run it on my station but as different user (for changing the user on that exe file shift + right mouse button):

```
using (Stream requestStream = restRequest.GetRequestStream())
```

**throws exception**

> No connectuion could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused if (ip address)

but when i copy the app to the other user station and try to run it it's work fine and doing exactly the same for my user

the problem is that the code should be integrated to application that use server that have wcf service that will send the sms's and the user that in iis applicationpool throwing that same exception

what could it be ?

my simple code:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, object> deserializedJsonDictionary;

HttpWebRequest restRequest;
WebResponse restResponse;

try
{
    string connectionParams = "{some json params for api...}";
    restRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
    restRequest.Method = Method; //post
    restRequest.ContentType = ContentType; // application/json

    using (Stream requestStream = restRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        byte[] inputStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(connectionParams);
        requestStream.Write(inputStringBytes, 0, inputStringBytes.Length);
    }

    using (restResponse = restRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = restResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string Json = rdr.ReadToEnd();

            deserializedJsonDictionary = (Dictionary<string, object>)jsonSerializer.DeserializeObject(Json);
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Are headers mismatching due to which it is refusing connection? What are Authentication/authorization requirements of service?

Comment: there is an username and password but it throw the refuse before it's gets to the server, in case that some of parameters are wrong the server returns json wit all the information

Comment: by saying username and password i mean local authentication (the api request the same in both cases)

Comment: In my experience I've gotten this when either 1) the API devs have set a call limit which you've exceeded for the given period, which could be user based, or 2) the service has asked you to provide an ip address list that it will accept requests from and you have made a call outside of the acceptable range of IPs

Comment: talked to the api providers there is no ip ranges and call limites, 1) running the application as is double click on exe will work fine 2) run as different user will throw exception 3) run one more time as is working (no limits)

Comment: and i tried from other station that belongs to the other user and it's the same problem but opposite

Comment: Does your machine have a firewall on it, probably the default Windows firewall? Turn that off and it will probably work. Either that or your network has a proxy server that needs configuring for the other user.

Comment: on the station my firewall is disabeled but the company have firewall tried to look with our IT if i have any block requests  and there is no issue with that... the same http pass in both cases (working and not) to the same destination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the problem solved

in our company we have proxy for connecting to the internet

when my user was logged on he has all the settings he needed from the GPO (include proxy)
when i tried to connect with other user he simply didn't have the proxy settings and that was the issue

what i did is simply added proxy to the code:

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("[my proxy address]", [my proxy port number]);
proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
request.Proxy = proxy;
```